# Application hangs during 'compileCoffeescript'

Tags: javascript, meteor

I've a meteor application which has a really weird behavior. Usually it hangs on startup and writing only:

```
sercan@home:~/meteor_work/***$ meteor
[[[[[ ~/meteor_work/mongoclient ]]]]]         

=> Started proxy.                             
=> Started MongoDB.                           
   Loading plugin 'compileCoffeescript' ...  -
```

What could be a problem here ?
Any help would be appreciated.

*p.s. meteor version 1.2.1*

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE:** After I remove `coffeescript@1.0.11` line from versions file it passed the compile phase and now stuck on:

```
Building for web.browser                  -
```

**UPDATE2:** I've read [this issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/5275) and decided to  comment out below ecmascript dependency:

```
#ecmascript              # Enable ECMAScript2015+ syntax in app code
```

Then it worked !!! But now I'm unable to use ECMAScript2015+ etc of course, anyway I dont need it. But I need a really brief explanation about this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestions who confronts these issues:

Try to remove some packages (which your meteor build stuck on) as follows from your **versions** file:

```
- less@2.5.1
- coffeescript@1.0.11
```

If it doesnt work try to comment out below line from your **packages** file:

```
#ecmascript              # Enable ECMAScript2015+ syntax in app code
```

Don't forget these files are included in your `.meteor` directory, also if you are working with `ECMAScript2015+` I have no idea what to do, this solution just worked for me.