# Stuck building a Meteor project

Tags: javascript, ios, meteor

I am trying to build a Meteor project by calling `meteor` in my terminal in the project directory. It keeps getting stuck on

```
=> Started proxy.                             
=> Started MongoDB.                           
   Loading plugin `compileLessBatch` fro...  /
```

I've built and ran the same project before, this never happened. I also just installed Ionic and its packages and dependencies, could it be the culprit?

Comment: Same problem here. Only happens after adding [phaser.min.js](https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/tree/master/build) (which is a **very large** file - 100k LoC) to my project. However, I'm not sure how a Javascript file should have any impact on less processors. Must be a bug.

Answer (score 2):

Delete mobile folders (for example 'android') and run 'meteor' again

Answer (score 0):

I've already confronted such issues and asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34490892/application-hangs-during-compilecoffeescript). Therefore noone can explicitly know what's happening on your side. But my suggestions:

Try to remove some packages as follows from your **versions** file:

```
- less@2.5.1
- coffeescript@1.0.11
```

If it doesnt work try to comment out below line from your **packages** file:

```
#ecmascript              # Enable ECMAScript2015+ syntax in app code
```

Don't forget these files are included in your `.meteor` directory.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded my app from 1.2 to 1.3. *mquandelle:bower* stopped working for that version. I didn't know that and installed it anyway and downloaded pdfMake from bower. When I realized bower was deprecated for 1.3, I remove the package and deleted the folder for pdfMake in .meteor.

As I needed pdfMake I copied the build directory from that app in my project's root. When I run my meteor app, this problem started showing.

There were four files from pdfMake. When I deleted two of them, this specific problem disappeared. They were big js files that were not needed because there existed the "min.js" version of those files.